# How to use root directory as the base url to render a html page?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I added name tags in my html pages using `'{% url 'blog-home' %}'` tag.
If i try to access it through navigation bar from root directory, it is opening correctly at `localhost:8000/blog` but when i again try to access it through navigation bar, it is taking relative path and redirects me to `localhost:8000/blog/blog` .

```
# views.py
def blog_main_page(request):
    return render(request, 'blog.html')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog_main_page, name='blog-home'),
]

# urls.py (Main App)
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

I expect the resulting url to be `localhost:8000/blog` but not `localhost:8000/blog/blog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## views.py

```
def blog_main_page(request):
    return render(request, '<App Name>/blog.html')
```

The app name is required as based on the standard structure of Django files , all HTML files are stored within the templates directory .

The structure is as follows:

```
~<App-Name>
  ~templates
    ~<App-Name>
      ~HTML Files
```

Comment: Actually my templates and static folder is in the main project folder. Should i move them to their respective apps?

Comment: Yes you should have the templates and static folder within the app folder itself.